# alarm set using timepicker not working, android

Tags: android, timepicker, android-alarms

i'm adding alarm to my app. when the time for appointment set from user using timepicker, i want to alert user with alarm. if i set to alarm, it only takes the last alarm i set, how i want to make both working?..

there's no error, and i register already in Manefest. actually i want to fetch date and time set in sqlite and the alarm is based on the date and time.i'm getting stuck, first i want user to add appointment, let say 25/4/2013 on 4.30pm.. the data is save in the sqlite. then on the day, i want the apps, to alarm the user.. how can i do that? i know using alarm manager but i don't know where to start from the code

and for the alarmReceiver i want the class to be able to alert the user maybe using alert or toast or notification. but i have try alert and toast cannot be used. is there any other way? 
Please help me
below is my code:

```
public class AppointmentAdd extends Activity 
{

private SQLiteDatabase database;
private DBHelper helper;
private ScheduleClient scheduleClient;
Button btnSave, btnDate, btnTime;
EditText addPurpose;

DateFormat fmtDateAndTime = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
        int dayOfMonth) {
    myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
    myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
    updateLabelDate(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
}
};

TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener t = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    myCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
    myCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    updateLabelTime(hourOfDay, minute);
}
};

private void updateLabelDate(int year, int monthOfYear,
        int dayOfMonth) {

    year = myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    monthOfYear = myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    dayOfMonth = myCalendar.get(Calendar.DATE);

    btnDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(dayOfMonth).append(".")
            .append(monthOfYear + 1).append(".").append(year).append(" "));
}

private void updateLabelTime(int hourOfDay, int minute) {

    hourOfDay = myCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minute = myCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    btnTime.setText(new StringBuilder().append(hourOfDay).append(":")
            .append(minute));
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.appointment_add);

    btnSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    btnDate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnTime = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    addPurpose = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    scheduleClient = new ScheduleClient(this);
    scheduleClient.doBindService();

    btnDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new DatePickerDialog(AppointmentAdd.this, d, myCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
        }
    });

    btnTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public  void onClick(View v) {
            new TimePickerDialog(AppointmentAdd.this, t, myCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), myCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.MINUTE), true).show();
        }

    });


    helper = new DBHelper(this);
    database = helper.getWritableDatabase();

    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String purpose = addPurpose.getText().toString();
            String date = btnDate.getText().toString();
            String time = btnTime.getText().toString();

            helper.insertDataAppointment(database, date, time, purpose);
            Toast.makeText(AppointmentAdd.this, "Successfully Add", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            setAlarm(myCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

            Intent i = new Intent(AppointmentAdd.this, AppointmentView.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    updateLabelDate(0, 0, 0);
    updateLabelTime(0, 0);
}

private void setAlarm(int Hour, int Minute){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Hour);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Minute);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    //in case of choosing a previous hour, then set alarm to next day
    if (cal.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis())
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Hour + 24);

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent Notifyintent = new Intent(this, Notify.class);
PendingIntent Notifysender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, Notifyintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 3600000, Notifysender);

    Toast.makeText(AppointmentAdd.this, "Alarm set successfully" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void onClickCancel(View v){
    startActivity (new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AppointmentView.class));
}

} // end class
```

and here my AlarmReceiver class:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      NotificationManager myNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
      Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Update Device", 0);
      Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, AppointmentView.class);
      PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
      notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Appointment", "Please check your appointment list", contentIntent);
      notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_HIGH_PRIORITY;
      myNotificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
}
```

Comment: Any errors while particular alarm time is reached or did you register the receiver in Manifest?

Comment: there's no error, and i register already in Manefest. actually i want to fetch date and time set in sqlite and the alarm is based on the date and time. i think my code is the function setAlarm wrong for this.. i'm getting stuck, first i want user to add appointment, let say 25/4/2013 on 4.30pm.. the data is save in the sqlite. then on the day, i want the apps, to alarm the user.. how can i do that? i know using alarm manager but i don't know where to start from the code

Comment: ok, it already can go to main menu, for the alarmreceiver class, can i do toast or alertdialog instead of change activity?

Comment: Yeah. First try with that. Actually I don't have enough time to post exact answer, but I can post my working code with some modifications if I get time. What do you say?

Comment: sure2.. no prob.. sorry to trouble you. i already try toast n alertdialog, i not applicable with broadReceiver

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to get you. You want me to post or not? Please use full words.

Comment: yes, i want you to post it..:)

Comment: i can get the notification bar already, but the alarm is for the latest one only, if two alarm i set, first 27/4/2013 4.10pm, then i set 27/4/2013 4.15pm.. it only alarm for the second one. how can i get all the data?

Answer (score 0):

**As per your comment:**

It's because the `pendingintent` needs different **request id** each time.

Now your present PendingIntent is in the below way:

```
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Here you are giving `reqid` as 0 every time, so instead of different pending intent being created, it's overriding the present pending intent, that is why you get the latest set alarm fired. So give unique request id with different number everytime like below.

```
 PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, reqid, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Even I had done the same thing as per your requirement which I had to store the entire data in the sqlite database about the messages and alarms. So, to set different `request id` each time, I have used primary key id which is in database to set for the pending intent. Hope this helps.

Comment: the regid need to iniliaze is it as variable?

Comment: It's an integer variable. You need to produce different number and assign to that variable each time.

Comment: yes, but now the prob is, i don't know how to fetch the date which i store as datetime in sqlite and use it as per code, hour, month, day, year.. i'm getting stuck

Comment: I think your questions have been gradually deviating from the original question you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
final int alarmId = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
PendingIntent pi =
  PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Date_Time.this, alarmId, i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Date_Time.this.ALARM_SERVICE);
manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cal.getTimeInMillis() , pi);
```